# Regular Expression to Match non HTML tags

Tags: regex

This is my RegEx that matches all HTMl tags. https://regex101.com/r/bDHD9z/3

```
<\/?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(?:".*?"|'.*?'|[^'">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)\/?>
```

I want to create opposite one, which matches everything but HTML tags. This regex should match inside and link from following text:

```
<span class="className" id='ID' name=name>inside</span>
<a href="" title="displays >">link</a>
```

I have tried to use negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/bDHD9z/4 It doesn't really do the opposite as I would expect.

HTML parser as some people suggested is not possible as I need to match other criteria using Regex

Comment: Get a HTML parser. Working XML or HTML with a regular expression is just asking for brittle code.

Comment: Simply use 'Replace on the match with an empty string, then you have the opposite

Comment: @PoulBak I want to use regex for match. If I use it with empty strings, I would not be able to run functions on the matched result and keep the HTML tags.

Comment: The best way is to use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` on the tags.

Comment: @sin I do not understand what you mean by `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

Comment: @Robert I do not think that I can use HTML parser as the text could also be something else for example `{value, plural, one {# book} other {# books}}` and I have to match book and books https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/issues/296#issuecomment-416610667 Let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: Use skip/fail if you're using the PCRE or Perl engines.

Comment: Don't! Please, just don't! I've learned this the hard way and didn't understand why parsing HTML with regex is a terrible idea until I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4934172) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4934172). `I need to match other criteria using Regex` Wouldn't it be easier to use an HTML parser and then use Regex to match whatever left to be matched?

Comment: I do not think so, because I have to pass results to library and I can not do it one by one. As I said I do not have to cover all html tags. The tags are coming from i18n and I only want to add pseudolocalization. There are certain tags that are supported and they are easily testable.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed How is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3390419) any useful? It's a bunch of rubbish.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness It's intended to look like this _in order to emphasize the hell you would go through if you decided to parse HTML with regex_. If you don't like it, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4934172) have a "more gentle" explanation. There are also other good answers in both questions.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't find that answer educational at all. Yeah I agree, some of the other answers in that question are actually useful. The first one should just be removed in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can not use a HTML parser, you can try this regex:

```
(?:>)(?:\s*|([^><]+))(?:<)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fSbZe9/3

Comment: It does not work if the text is outside HTML tags https://regex101.com/r/fSbZe9/2

Comment: I used this variant `(?:>\s*)([^><\n\r]+\s*)(?:<)` as the text after a new line is not match with the original regex. See example https://regex101.com/r/1n0xHn/1